# Query the minimum price from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

One table contain a different laptop specifications

```
laptop:
|partNumber|picture|laptopName|laptopProcessor|visibility|
..........................................................
|AB00001   |pic1   |lenovo..  |intel core I5  |1         |
|AB00002   |pic2   |samsung   |AMD semprom 3.8|1         |
```

The other table is an inventory table, I have a multiple shops every shop has a different price for the specific laptops

```
inventory:
|partNumber|shopName|price|qty|
...............................
|AB00001   |shop1   |554  |2  |
|AB00002   |shop1   |356  |4  |
|AB00002   |shop3   |400  |1  |
|AB00001   |shop4   |625  |5  |
|AB00002   |shop4   |345  |3  |
```

I want to write a query which make a list about the laptops with the best price so I wrote this:

```
SELECT laptop.partNumber, laptop.picture, laptop.laptopName, laptop.laptopProcessor,
       inventory.MIN(price)
FROM laptop INNER JOIN inventory ON inventory.partNumber=laptop.partNumber
WHERE visibility="1"
```

So basically I want to show all laptop with the best price, it is working without price query, but I cannot add this MIN() function to the query I think I miss the syntax, but I don't know how should be work. Please help me.

Comment: change it to read laptop.partNumber = inventory.partNumber and try running it again

Comment: `MIN(inventory.price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `MIN(column name)`, so it should be `MIN(inventory.price)`. But **you also need to add a `GROUP BY` clause**, otherwise you will have only one result for the whole table.

Then, since you want to group by laptop, add `GROUP BY inventory.partNumber`. If `partNumber` is not a *primary key* of `laptop` table, you should also add other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT laptop.partNumber,
  laptop.picture,
  laptop.laptopName,
  laptop.laptopProcessor,
  MIN(inventory.price)
FROM laptop
INNER JOIN inventory ON inventory.partNumber = laptop.partNumber
WHERE visibility = "1"
GROUP BY laptop.partNumber,
  laptop.picture,
  laptop.laptopName,
  laptop.laptopProcessor
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Group BY

```
SELECT laptop.partNumber, laptop.picture, laptop.laptopName, laptop.laptopProcessor,
       inventory.MIN(inventory.price)
FROM laptop INNER JOIN inventory ON inventory.partNumber=laptop.partNumber
WHERE visibility="1"
GROUP BY laptop.partNumber, laptop.picture, laptop.laptopName, laptop.laptopProcessor
```